# How to solve java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When I try and do a putItem on my DynamoDbTable it times out with

2023-04-21 14:54:39.772 ERROR 20904 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com:443

I tried to do a putItem on my dynamodb table.  I was expecting it to not timeout

Answer (score 0):

My bet here is that you do not have a valid internet connection to where you're making the request from, or port 443 is blocked. I suggest running some basic network trouble shooting from whichever medium you're running your code from.